# Как проверить сгенерированный и возвращённый токен?

Tags: django, angular2, csrf

Помогите пожалуйста понять как проверить форму, которая ранее получила токен.

Допустим, на сервере 1 есть Django. На серевере 2 есть angular4. Кроссдоменные запросы настроены. Генерация html происходит НЕ на бекенде

На стороне фронтэнда в шаблоне отрисовывается форма. При этом чуть ранее(сразу при заходе на страницу, на которой есть эта форма) делается ajax-запрос к серверу 1, в результате которого с сервера 1 приходит сгенерированный токен. Итак, форма теперь имеет поле типа hidden, в котором содержится токен.

Далее пользователь заполняет форму и нажимает кнопку submit. В результате форма отправляет свои данные в виде POST-запроса на сервер 1. На сервере 1 view принимает эти данные.

Вопрос: как в view можно проверить, что пришёл именно тот токен, который был сгенерирован ранее, а не какой-то другой?

Предполагается, что в django используется стандартный middleware CSRF, который идёт с фреймворком по умолчанию

Comment: Этот middleware сам всё проверяет и ничего делать не нужно, не? Хотя вообще о каком токене речь?

Comment: Речь о csrf-токене, которым подписывается форма.

Не совсем понятно как django сам проверяет вернувшийся токен. То есть django прежде чем отправить токен форме запоминает адрес странички, на которой эта форма?

И как это middleware сам проверит токен? А если например я отправляю с одной странички несколько форм?

Comment: Про это немного есть в официальной документации https://djbook.ru/rel1.7/ref/contrib/csrf.html , алсо токен многоразовый